# How do you ensure C++20 support?

Tags: c++, linux, centos, c++20

I have `g++` installed on CentOS9

```
g++ (GCC) 11.2.1 20220127 (Red Hat 11.2.1-9)
```

I can compile with switch `-std=c++20` without errors/warnings.

When I search filesystem for '11' I find

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/11
/usr/include/c++/11
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/11
```

But when I search for '20' I get nothing.

How do I "install" C++ 20 ? What is it and how can it be done on RH/CentOS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`11` in the file path is the compiler version, not the C++ version. So it is not a problem that there is no corresponding path with a `20`.

If `-std=c++20` doesn't give an error, you have (at least to some degree) C++20 support.

Theoretically there is the [`__cplusplus`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#Predefined_macros) macro, which is predefined to a value of at least `202002L` for enabled C++20 support, but in practice that doesn't mean that all C++20 features are supported.

There are further feature-specific [feature test macros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test) that may be of help.

For an overview of what exactly is supported in which compiler version see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support, as well as the corresponding pages of the individual compilers.

As you can see there, with GCC 11 you have mostly complete C++20 support, except for few items, especially in the standard library, such as for example full module support, `constexpr` for `std::string` and `std::vector`, atomic shared pointers and notably `std::format`.